# Spark for Constraint Engine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, constraints

I have just started learning Spark and have setup a small cluster too on top of Yarn and Hdfs. I have submitted small jobs for testing as well. However, I want to know if we can use Spark as a realtime constraint engine. Let me give an example. I want to build a web app where a user provides a JSON object via API. The user also provides some constraints (if some_value < 100 remove the the row etc). Can I perform these operations concurrently using Spark and provide quick response to the client (response to be provided as a response of the API). One important requirement being, I will have to provide response in a very short time, lesser than a second.

I see that Spark is all about submitting jobs and processing them concurrently. Can the above requirements be fulfilled by Spark?

Comment: Spark is all about distributed processing of data be it real-time or batch. Your use case needs a storage system on which you can apply filters and get results back quickly. You can use spark for ingesting data if the storage choice is a distributed one. A little more context would help to give more suggestions.

Comment: hi @nanic I have pasted more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800504/slow-performance-of-spark Please do have a look and let me if we can use spark for such case.